# Calculating and Saving the custom field

Tags: acumatica

I have a bound custom field grossprofit added into the SOLine grid which is calculated based on Item UnitCost, AverageCost and Qty.

I have the code written into SOLine_CuryUnitPrice_FieldSelecting event. However, it is not saving into the Database.

Also, I need a total of all lineitems for the custom field as a TotalGrossProfit on Order summary. It is calculating but for some reason it is not reflecting on screen.

Can anyone suggest?

Here is the code

```html
public class SOOrderExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
{
 #region UsrTotalGrossProfit

 public abstract class usrTotalGrossProfit : PX.Data.IBqlField
 {
 }
 protected Decimal? _UsrTotalGrossProfit;

 [PXCurrency(typeof(SOOrder.curyInfoID), typeof(SOOrder.orderWeight))]
 [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Gross Profit")]
 public virtual Decimal? UsrTotalGrossProfit
 {
  get
  {
   return this._UsrTotalGrossProfit;
  }
  set
  {
   this._UsrTotalGrossProfit = value;
  }
 }
 #endregion
}

public class SOLineExtension : PXCacheExtension<SOLine>
{
 #region UsrGrossProfit

 public abstract class usrGrossProfit : PX.Data.IBqlField
 {
 }
 protected Decimal? _UsrGrossProfit;

 [PXDBCurrency(typeof(SOOrder.curyInfoID), typeof(SOOrder.discTot))]
 [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Gross Profit")]
 public virtual Decimal? UsrGrossProfit
 {
  get
  {
   return this._UsrGrossProfit;
  }
  set
  {
   this._UsrGrossProfit = value;
  }
 }
 #endregion
}

public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{ 
 protected virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
 {
  SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
  if (row == null) return;

  SOOrderExtension orderExtension = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(row);

  foreach (SOLine soLine in Base.Transactions.Select())
  {
   SOLineExtension lineItem = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>(soLine);

   orderExtension.UsrTotalGrossProfit = orderExtension.UsrTotalGrossProfit + lineItem.UsrGrossProfit;
  }
 }
   
 protected void SOLine_CuryUnitPrice_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
 {
  var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

  if (row != null && Base.Document.Current != null && Base.Document.Current.Status != "C")
  {
   SOLineExtension opportunity = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>(row);

   InventoryItem inv = PXSelect<InventoryItem,
    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), row.InventoryID);

   if (inv.ItemType == "F")      // Stock Item
   {
    opportunity.UsrGrossProfit = (row.UnitPrice - invc.AvgCost) * row.Qty;
   }

   Base.Save.Press();
   Base.Persist();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Try this, not sure this may work. Just assign the value in your field selecting event, don't call save and persist actions.
protected virtual void SOLine_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        {
            SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;
            if (row != null)
            {
                SOLineExtension opportunity = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>(row);

                if(opportunity != null)
                    opportunity.UsrGrossProfit = (row.UnitPrice - invc.AvgCost) * row.Qty;
            }
        }

Comment: Yes indeed calling Save/Persist in FieldSelecting should be avoided. You should only provide the value in there and let the user click on save button to persist it.

Comment: These values are automatically calculated every time and I do not want User to click Save every time they navigate Sales Orders

Comment: @John - Tried SOLine_RowPersisting event. These event does not get executed while navigating the records.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two events that I would use.. you may have to change them to your version of C# i am using 7...

```
protected void SOLine_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.row is SOLine row) return;
        if (!e.oldRow is SOLine oldRow) return;
        //check for unwanted status, if true return
        if (Base.Document.Current.Status == "C") return;
        //check for the fields to have value, if no return
        if (!row.UnitPrice.HasValue || !row.Qty.HasValue) return;
        //get row extension
        var rowExt = row..GetExtension<SOLineExtension>();
        //select inventory record
        var invItem = (InventoryItem)PXSelect<InventoryItem,
            Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID);    
        if (invItem == null) return;
        //add value to field, no persist or save
        if (inv.ItemType == "F")      // Stock Item
        {
            rowExt.UsrGrossProfit = (row.UnitPrice - invc.AvgCost) * row.Qty;
        }           
    }

    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this may not work in older versions of C#
        if (!(e.row is SOOrder row) return;

        var rowExt = row.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>();

        foreach (SOLine soLine in Base.Transactions.Select())
        {
            var lineItem = soLine.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>();
            rowExt.UsrTotalGrossProfit += lineItem.UsrGrossProfit;
        }
        //this is probably why not showing up...
        Base.Document.Cache.Update(Base.Document.Current);
    }
```

Comment: I do not think RowUpdated and RowSelected event will work in this case it is not even executing while navigating the Sales Orders

Comment: Also updating the Base data in RowSelected event will end up in an infinite loop